# what is the status of AMD's Open Source 7000 series drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, open-source

I've seen announcements that AMD released open source drivers for the 7000 series of GPUs earlier this year, but not much since then. Are they in the kernel or are there plans to integrate them?

If so, will 12.04 ever get them, and will it just be a matter of switching from the proprietary drivers to the open source drivers?